# Google indexing pages too slowly.

Tags: wordpress, seo

Is there anything I can do to speed up the time it takes to index my pages? It's currently indexing them on it's own time I believe which is every 2 - 3 days and when working in music and media I need to have the latest post fairly quickly.

My robots file is.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
sitemap: http://vipes.us/sitemapindex.xml
```

If I am understanding this correctly, I would put this url into google 
http://vipes.us/sitemapindex.xml

But in doing so I still only get some of my pages indexed? Anybody care to take a look.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited to [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange than SO

Comment: Cross-posted on Webmasters: [Google Indexing Pages Very Slowly](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/63152/17633)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem, are you using a sitemap plugin? I've noticed that if you create your own XML sitemap or use something similar to [this](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/) the pages get crawled faster. I've just started using plugins and its very slow, but when I used the generator it was faster for Google to crawl (index) my pages.

Comment: Thank you for this, Actually helped quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If your's is a new site site, then it would take sometime to get indexed ( all pages) by google.. since it inspects the content based on many things. Considering your site it would be a while to get indexed..

Comment: That does not make much sense honestly because I have over 2500 pages in my website that ARE indexed but it took them all about 4 - 5 days to get indexed, When it should have only taken them 15/20 minutes..